# Minimum SHA256'd UTF8 encoded passphrase length not stored anywhere

Tags: entropy, sha256, passphrase, unicode, bitcoin

For a passphrase that is UTF8 encoded and then SHA256'd, what is the minimum length to achieve a practically collision free result?

The implementation is for a 32 byte cryptocurrency ed25519 seed thus will not be stored anywhere by the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I cringe at the idea of a simple hashing over a passphrase, but let's assume that it is actually OK in your setup.

The direct answer to your question is simple: *practically*, there are no collisions in SHA-256, regardless of input length. If you input two distinct sequences of bytes (e.g. two passphrases), you will get two distinct output. Mathematically, we know that collisions MUST exist (SHA-256 input space is larger than the output space), but we found none yet, and the best known methods for finding collisions have average cost *2<sup>128</sup>*, i.e. a lot more than is feasible with existing technology.

Input length and encoding have nothing whatsoever to do with the subject. How you imagined that input length, furthermore *minimum* input length, or encoding, had an impact on collisions, is a mystery to me -- so I have to assume that you do not worry about *SHA-256* collisions. Instead, maybe you worry about the probability of two distinct people coming up, out of (bad) luck, with the same passphrase ? (SHA-256 being there a red herring.)

If *that* is your actual question, then it depends on the process by which the passphrases are generated, which has only a very distant relationship with the passphrase length. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase/6096#6096) for details on how to calculate entropy (because an entropy of "*n* bits" roughly translates to a probability of collision of about *t<sup>2</sup>/n*, as per the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Comment: For theory and practice of password hashing, read [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846). Now.